# List sourced workspaces

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm experimenting with shell plugins, dynamically updating command line prompt.

Currently I'm running Zsh + OhMyZsh + powerlevel10k

I've managed to add ROS2 distro name and ROS2 domain ID to the command prompt. That was easy: I've added a shell function looking at environment vars `ROS_DISTRO` and `ROS_DOMAIN_ID`:

```
function prompt_my_ros2_env() {
    if [[ -v ROS_DISTRO ]]; then
        local ros_domain_id=""
        if [[ -v ROS_DOMAIN_ID ]]; then
            ros_domain_id="[$ROS_DOMAIN_ID]"
        fi

        p10k segment -t "$ROS_DISTRO$ros_domain_id"
    fi
}
POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS+=my_ros2_env
```

Now I wonder, is it possible to create a list of sourced ROS2 workspaces?

I can see that some environment variables change after execution of `source ./install/local_setup.zsh` command, for example `AMENT_PREFIX_PATH`, `PYTHONPATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. But sourcing one workspace adds several directories to almost each of them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386860/list-sourced-workspaces/) by [wl](https://answers.ros.org/users/68917/wl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2021-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure whether this would help you, but if you use `colcon`, `COLCON_PREFIX_PATH` can be used to know sourced workspaces.

---

Originally posted by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) with karma: 307 on 2021-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wl](https://answers.ros.org/users/68917/wl/) on 2021-09-23**:
Indeed, this variable contains the list of of sourced workspaces. Thank you!
Unfortunately, my initial idea is not very useful, because this list occupies a lot of space, I'm not sure how to compress it and if I need it at all.